# Merging 3 consecutive lines with swap

Tags: awk, sed

Hey I need to merge three consecutive lines with swap between 2nd and 3rd line in 'file':

```
$cat file
Object Name: A
    comments: comment A
    manual_encdomain: Name: A 
Object Name: B
    comments: comment B
    manual_encdomain: Name: B
```

So instead of output below :

```
$sed 'N;N;s/\n/ /g' file 
Object Name: A comments: comment A manual_encdomain: Name: A 
Object Name: B comments: comment B manual_encdomain: Name: B
```

I would rather need this

```
Object Name: A manual_encdomain: Name: A comments: comment A
Object Name: B manual_encdomain: Name: B comments: comment B
```

sed, awk anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use sed to swap lines:

```
$ sed -E 'N;N;s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/ \2 \1/' file
Object Name: A     manual_encdomain: Name: A      comments: comment A
Object Name: B     manual_encdomain: Name: B      comments: comment B
```

Or, equivalently:

```
$ sed  'N;N;s/\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)/ \2 \1/g' file
Object Name: A     manual_encdomain: Name: A      comments: comment A
Object Name: B     manual_encdomain: Name: B      comments: comment B
```

#### How it works:

- `-E`

  This turns on extended regular expressions.    (`-E` works on both BSD (OSX) sed and modern GNU sed.  For older versions of GNU sed, use `-r` instead.)

  Without extended regex, we need to escape `(` and `)` as shown above.
- `N;N`

  This reads in the second and third lines.
- `s/\n([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)/ \2 \1/`

  This swap the second and third lines.  The first occurrence of `\n([^\n]*)` captures the second line and saves it in capture group 1.  The second occurrence of `\n([^\n]*)` captures the third line and saves it in capture group 2.  The replacement text, `\2 \1` swaps the position while replacing the newlines with spaces.

#### Removing some excess white space

The second and third lines are indented in the input file.  If we want to remove that extra whitespace:

```
$ sed -E 'N;N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*([^\n]*)\n[[:blank:]]*([^\n]*)/ \2 \1/g' file
Object Name: A manual_encdomain: Name: A  comments: comment A
Object Name: B manual_encdomain: Name: B  comments: comment B
```

`[[:blank:]]` is the unicode-safe way to match blanks and tabs.

Comment: apreciate but I got sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: @irom What OS are you on?  Try `-r` in place on `-E`.

Comment: Changing your solution to use BREs is pretty much trivial.

Comment: This is old rhel 5;)

Comment: @irom Very good.  Old GNU used `-r` instead of `-E`.  Otherwise, escape the parens as I show in the updated answer and neither option is needed.

Comment: @SatōKatsura Good point!  Answer updated to show a BRE version.

Answer (score 7):

with awk:

```
awk '{line1=$0; getline line2; getline line3; print line1, line3, line2}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ex` and `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^O/+m +2' 'g/^O/j 3' %p | ex file.txt
```

Change the `%p` to an `x` to actually save changes when you're happy with the output.

---

**g**lobally, on lines starting (`^`) with a capital O, move (`m`) the next line (`+`) to after the second-next line (`+2`).

Then, globally, on each line starting with O, join three lines together.

Print all lines `%p`.

Or, save and exit `x`.